# Discord level bot for ONLY images and videos, errors when reading attachments (larger than 1)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have searched far and wide, and I found many things relating to the `.attachments` and how to read them from a message from a user. I am able to do that, but only for the first attachment. Every time I try to either A: Read successive attachments or B: Cycle through attachments, it gives a "attachments has no attribute 'size'" error, and when trying to cycle through (for example, for i in (message.attachments):) it says it is unable to do so because message.attachments is not a list, it is 'Attachments', and cannot be iterated through. I'm new to discord bots, and would like someone to help me figure out the attachments within the api, and maybe clean up the code/explain why if you feel inclined, as my programming can be very sloppy.

My bot, when done, will be a level system for only images and videos. Once a user reaches a level, they get a new rank, e.g. 'Photo Enthusiast'. It will have some other commands like !rank, but this is the main struggle I have been having, with working with the attachments. Any help is appreciated :)

Current code runs, but does not account for multiple files. I forget what code I have tried to use to do the xp levels, but my thought process this time around was to add 1 to a placeholder variable, then add xp for the amount of times an attachment was detected (have not done the only png/jpg/jpeg/mov/mp4 formats yet)

Code:

```
### IMPORTS ###
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import json
from keep_alive import keep_alive #a file used to ping the bot so as not to deacivate it aka a webserver
import math as m


### VARIABLES ###
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


###########################
 
with open("users.json", "ab+") as ab:
    ab.close()
    f = open('users.json','r+')
    f.readline()
    if os.stat("users.json").st_size == 0:
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    else:
      pass
 
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
  users = json.load(f)


### EVENTS ###
@bot.event    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
      with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

      ### MESSAGE XP ###
      xp = 0
      try:
        url = message.attachments[0].url
      except IndexError:
        print("Error - Index")
      else:
        xp += 1

      if xp > 0:
        for i in xp:
          await add_experience(users, message.author)
          await level_up(users, message.author, message)

      with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            await bot.process_commands(message)

### COMMANDS ###
@bot.command()
async def rank(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    userlvl = users[f'{ctx.author.id}']['level']
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You are at level {userlvl}!')
  else:
    userlvl2 = users[f'{member.id}']['level']
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} is at level {userlvl2}!')


###########################
 
keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

EDIT: This is an example of a piece of code I have tried that throws an error, replacing the ### MESSAGE XP ### Code:

```
      ### MESSAGE XP ###
      xp = 0
      for i in message.attachments:
        try:
          url = message.attachments[i].url
        except IndexError:
          print("Error - Index")
        else:
          xp += 1

      if xp > 0:
        for i in xp:
          await add_experience(users, message.author)
          await level_up(users, message.author, message)

      with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Can you please include the code that throws the error?

Comment: Included! Thanks, forgot to add that part when I was writing it up @Chuaat